# Android adb push permission denied

Tags: android

I am trying to edit the `handheld_core_hardware.xml` in `system/etc/permissions 
when i push the file after editing it gives that error

> adb: error: failed to copy 'handheld_core_hardware.xml' to '/system/etc/permissions/handheld_core_hardware.xml': remote Permission denied
>   handheld_core_hardware.xml: 0 files pushed. 0.8 MB/s (4027 bytes in 0.005s)

even that i have changed the file to read-write not read-only

Comment: Permission denied means that you don't have root rights.

Answer (score 0):

Is your device rooted ? I think in order to manipulate those files you have root permissions.

Comment: Try the workarounds described in answer 1 and 2 from this thread: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110162/adb-push-permission-denied